# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar mi consulta con varios JOINS postgresql?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

¡Buen día a todos!

Estoy intentando hacer la optimización de una consulta para un reporte de odoo. La consulta no es compleja, sin embargo, existen varios JOINS que hacen complicado y tardado el proceso.

```
select
      min(l.id) as id,
      count(*) as nbr,
      s.date_order as date,
      sum(l.qty * u.factor) as product_qty,
      sum(l.qty * l.price_unit) as price_total,
      sum((l.qty * l.price_unit) * (l.discount / 100)) as total_discount,
      sum(cast(to_char(date_trunc('day',s.date_order) - date_trunc('day',s.create_date),'DD') as int)) as delay_validation,
      s.partner_id as partner_id,
      s.state as state,
      s.user_id as user_id,
      s.location_id as location_id,
      s.company_id as company_id,
      s.sale_journal as journal_id,
      l.product_id as product_id,
      pt.categ_id as product_categ_id
from pos_order_line as l
      inner join pos_order s on (s.id=l.order_id)
      inner join product_product p on (p.id=l.product_id)
      inner join product_template pt on (pt.id=p.product_tmpl_id)
      inner join product_uom u on (u.id=pt.uom_id)
group by
      s.date_order, s.partner_id,s.state, pt.categ_id,s.user_id,s.location_id,s.company_id,s.sale_journal,l.product_id,s.create_date
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para cada Hash Join he intentado generar indices como:
create index pos_order_line_index ON pos_order_line (product_id) include (qty, price_unit, discount) 
Esto con el fin de optimizar el propio join que trabaja en paralelo con otros. Al ser un SELECT, leí que no afecta tener otros indicies, es más, puedes tener varios indices y ayuda solamente en los SELECT. Dicho esto, cree como indices cada uno de los campos dentro del primer Group Key y tampoco ha reducido. He creado indices para cada tabla de cada join y aún siguen sin mejora. Tengo entendido que, cuando se toma en cuenta un indice en la consulta, dentro del EXPLAIN ANALYZE indica IDEX SCAN e INDEX COND, pero veo que, después de todos los indices que he intentado, no aparece nada de eso. Espero alguien me pueda ayudar con este tema.

Comment: No agreges codigo como foto sino como texto.

Comment: @alanfcm ¡Entendido! Ya lo cambié.

Comment: y si hace varias consultas, es decir un "divide y venceras", como estrategia puede iniciar haciendo la consultas sin `JOINS`e ir agregando uno por uno y detenerse en la que cause la demora y después analizar como obtener el resto de información.